# Remove msgid from .po file

Tags: gettext

I'm trying to remove a list of msgids from a .pot file. Is there some commandline tool which is capable of doing something like

```
msgdelete "foo*" bar.pot
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround but it feels very dirty. Here I want to remove all msgids which consist of a single number or char:

```
msggrep -Ke '^[0-9a-z]$' project.pot > remove.po
msgcomm -u project.pot remove.po -o project.pot
rm remove.po
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a better solution after all these years? I ran into the same issue, and any evolution that you could share would be much appreciated. And thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @rffontenelle No, I'm sorry